# Nginx not serving javascript files

Tags: nginx

I have a server running Nginx, and I have two locations in the same server block.  I'm using this as a reverse proxy for my node.js express application.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com**

```
server {

server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /otherapp{
    root /home/ubuntu/otherapp;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4444;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
...
```

The application running on the www.example.com location works as intended, and all the css and js files load.  But on the www.example.com/otherapp location, the html file is served but the js fails to load with a status 404.  The browser sends a GET to https://example.com/index.js

**Express Code for /otherapp**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//things for express
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); //static directory


//qrcode is base route
app.get('/qrcode', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html')
});


//start server
var port = 4444;
var ip;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"){
    ip = 'serverip';
}
else{
    ip = 'localhost';
}
app.listen(port, ip, function(){
    console.log(`starting server on ${ip}:${port}`)
});
```

**/home/ubuntu/otherapp/public/index.html**

```html
...
<script src="./index.js"></script>
...
```

index.js is located in the same folder as index.html

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

I woule have used:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

Though this is mostly useful during devs, when I do not have a webserver aside from NodeJS. Otherwise, I'ld rather serve static file with Nginx, in your case:

```
location /otherapp/public {
    root /home/ubuntu/otherapp;
}

location /otherapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4444;
    xxx
}
```